# sharing with external users via powershell

Tags: external-users, communication-site

The tenancy is set to Allow users to invite and share with authenticated external users and it works for site collections created from the admin center.

I am trying to set a communication site to the exact value and I am using this powershell script.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://XXXXXXX -SharingCapability ExternalUserAndGuestSharing
```

I get an error message saying that

> The SharingCapability set for this SPOSite will not take effect
>   until the 'ExternalUserAndGuestSharing' SharingCapability is also
>   enabled on the SPOTenant.

I thought ExternalUserAndGuestSharing was the same as "`Allow users to invite and share with authenticated external users`" but it does not seem the case.

What am I doing wrong?

I would like to avoid to set the tenancy to "`Allow sharing to authenticated external users and using anonymous access links`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use below command for external sharing with authenticated external user with valid email address.

```
Set-SPOSite -Identity https://XXXXXXX -SharingCapability ExternalUserSharingOnly
```

Assuming you have below set at Tenant level

> “Allow external users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as
>   authenticated users”

Regarding ExternalUserAndGuestSharing - External user sharing (share by email) and guest link sharing are both enabled, this is for anonymous access.

Refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enabled-external-sharing-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/) for more details